# Make object-fit & object-position work in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer, css-sprites

I have this in my css file:

```
.apiscar1 {   
    object-fit: none; 
    object-position: -354px 0; 
    width: 85px;  
    height: 155px; 
}
.apiscar2 { 
    object-fit: none; 
    object-position: -189px 0;
    width: 155px;     
    height: 155px; 
}
```

And I call the `sprite.png` img src on my wordpress page.
This works perfectly for a lot of images placed into the `sprites.png` but it doesn't work in IE. How do I make it work in IE?

Comment: try `display:block;`

Comment: unsure what you mean. What am i replacing with display:block?

Comment: add that to your css classes

Comment: i added this to the code: '.apiscar1 { display:block; object-fit: none; object-position: -354px 0; width: 85px;  height: 155px;' but it didnt work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Object-fit and object-position are not supported in IE/Edge.

Comment: I know. So how do people do sprites while taking this in to account?

Comment: Since Edge 16 there is partial support for `<img>` tag. See https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Answer (score 0):

I use a workaround where I set the image as a background on an element, background-size can be used as replacement for object-fit and background-position for object-position

Here is a jsfiddle with your example. https://jsfiddle.net/124f0hve/

```
.apiscar1 {   
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/");
    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: -354px 0; 
    width: 85px;  
    height: 155px; 
}
.apiscar2 { 
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/");
    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: -189px 0;
    width: 155px;     
    height: 155px; 
}
```

I used lorempixel images, you get random images on every change. If you look in the network, you will see the full image that was fetched and on the screen it shows only a portion of it.
I hope this helps.

Comment: could you give me an example of this using my code please (or other code)

Comment: I don't know if you have seen it, but I added an example last week. Hope it helped with your issue

Answer (score 0):

Make some div with `position: relative` as a wrapper and image position set as a absolute. Then use `top`, `right`, `left`, `bottom` to set position of image. This is workaround for object-positioning for IE.